# Cannot encode string to utf8 and utf8 to base64 in swift

Tags: swift, utf-8, base64, encode

I'm looking for a way to encode a string to UTF8 and then to base 64 in Swift 3.x

In swift 2.x I was using this way :

```
let pass: NSString = "test"    
let variable: NSString = (pass.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([]))!
```

XCode force me to put : NSUTF8StringEncoding.rawValue and then the result is not correct.

If someone has a solution :)

Thank

Comment: You say "in Swift 2.x I was using". Is your question asking how to write this code in Swift 3?

Comment: @rmaddy yes, I would like to do it in Swift 3

Comment: You should state that in your question.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 3, it's neater now:

```
let pass = "test"
let variable = pass.data(using: .utf8)!.base64EncodedString()
```

And you might want to use better named variables than *variable*.

If you need to deal with `NSString`:

```
let pass: NSString = "test"
let variable = (pass as String).data(using: .utf8)!.base64EncodedString()
```

Comment: It works just fine in an iOS Playground page. It is about iOS (and not macOS), right?

Comment: @Snooze Note that in this answer, `NSString` is not being used. A standard Swift `String` is being used.